# Photon absorption and Sight

Tags: photons

If light is made by emitting photons and photons are absorbed by our eyes to see light
then i have this question:
if there is one person in the room and he looks at a light source (L) with x photons emitted

then there is another room and there are 10 people who look at light source (L) which has same amount x photons.

then do the people in the room with 10 people see the light source x/10 darker as in 1/10 of the photons emitted are absorbed by each person?

basically i think my question boils down to can two people view the same photon of light??

Comment: It is very unclear what you are getting at with your question! Photons are not homing devices that fly towards eyes. But the number of photons that reach each pupil is determined primarily by the geometry of the problem, not by the number of pupils in the room. Most of the photons will just get absorbed by the walls! So the brightness will not be altered due to the amount of people in the room. (But it is true one photon can only be absorbed at one place!).

Answer (score 1):

Two people cannot view the same photon of light, because it is destroyed in effect upon being absorbed. However this does not decrease the overall brightness of the light source if more than one person observes it because your eye was not going to capture those photons anyway. Think about it this way. The brightness of the Sun here on earth is not changed by the presence of other planets (that are not directly in front of the Sun), because the earth is in a certain path to capture a certain set of photons of the Sun. The same is true for your observers in the room.